# Is there any console log in Dreamweaver CC?

Tags: javascript

Every time, when I want to test some javascript codes, I need to open a browser window as to checking the console log by using

```
console.log('something need to be tested');
```

Is there any console log like the one inside Chrome in Dreamweaver CC, to help the web developers to be more convenience from checking out any errors in javascript?

Thanks so much if anyone can help!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by navigating through

```
 Right click on it with Finder/Explorer, and choose to open it with DW.  Or, in DW's Files panel, browse to the log file, right click it and select Open with Dreamweaver.
```

Or you can setup [Free trace console](http://www.mydreamweaverextensions.com/my-dreamweaver-extensions/trace-console-insert.php) for doing it
Source: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/913504